# How to compare List of HashMap with selected keys

Tags: java, data-structures, hashmap

I have 2 list that needs to be compare and get the List A hashmap is match List B hashmap. If any one HahMap matched then say "matched"

Here is the structure

List 1 :-

```
[{level=3, SubTypeId=12345, TypeId=65}, {level=4, SubTypeId=2310, TypeId=7230}, {level=4, SubTypeId=2311, TypeId=7230}]
```

List 2:

```
[{TypeId=12345, SubTypeId=65}, {TypeId=8100, SubTypeId=63}]
```

Here List1 hashMap has extra field called `level`

HashMap `{TypeId=12345, SubTypeId=65}` is common on both the list.

Comment: If you do not loop through the entire List, how could you tell if the elements that you didn't inspect wouldn't match? It is impossible.

Comment: Edited the questions. I was asking is there any built in comparator to compare passing the keys

Comment: Doubtful there's any _built-in_ comparator that will be of any use.  You'll probably need to write your own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best you can do is *break* when a match is found. The following code shows how to do that using `anyMatch`. In the worst case scenario though, each map in one list will need to be compared with each map in the other. There is no way around that.

```
List<Map<String, Integer>> list1, list2;
...
boolean matched = list2.stream()
        .anyMatch(list2Map -> list1.stream()
                .anyMatch(map -> map.get("SubTypeId").equals(list2Map.get("SubTypeId"))
                        && map.get("TypeId").equals(list2Map.get("TypeId"))));
System.out.println(matched);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
package com.era.demo;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

public class CompareListHashMap {public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<HashMap<String, Integer>> list1 = Arrays.asList(new HashMap<String, Integer>() {{
        put("level", 3);
        put("SubTypeId", 12345);
        put("TypeId", 65);
    }},
    new HashMap<String, Integer>() {{
        put("level", 4);
        put("SubTypeId", 2310);
        put("TypeId", 7230);
    }},
    new HashMap<String, Integer>() {{
        put("level", 4);
        put("SubTypeId", 2311);
        put("TypeId", 7230);
    }});

    List<HashMap<String, Integer>> list2 = Arrays.asList(
            new HashMap<String, Integer>() {{
                 put("SubTypeId", 12345);
                 put("TypeId", 65);
             }},
            new HashMap<String, Integer>() {{
                put("SubTypeId", 8100);
                put("TypeId", 63);
            }});
   if (list1.stream().anyMatch(stringIntegerHashMap -> list2.stream().anyMatch(stringIntegerHashMap1 ->
            stringIntegerHashMap.get("SubTypeId").equals(stringIntegerHashMap1.get("SubTypeId")) && stringIntegerHashMap.get("TypeId").equals(stringIntegerHashMap1.get("TypeId")))))
       System.out.println("Matched");
}}
```

Comment: how is it different than the other answer?

Comment: @Kartik this would be the complete picture of the code